# JS Error when calling function with argument from Template Literal

Tags: javascript, template-literals

I'm using Template Literals to insert content into the page:

```
entries.forEach((entry) => {
  let id = entry.id;
  entryList.innerHTML += `
  <div class="entry">
      <button class="delete-btn" onclick="deleteEntry(${id})">D</button>
  </div>`;
});
```

And I'm getting "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token" when clicking the button.

But if I instead do in the button:

```
<button class="delete-btn" onclick="deleteEntry(3)">D</button>
```

The error does not happen.

Can you please tell me what's wrong here? Thank you.

Comment: When you looked at the HTML that was generated, what did it say instead of `deleteEntry(3)`?

Comment: That should be okay provided the button IDs are numbers (like the `3` you've shown). That said, `+=` with `innerHTML` is almost always a bad idea, as are `onxyz`-attribute-style event handlers. Instead: https://pastebin.com/ZhTx9Zer But neither of those things should be resulting in a syntax error.

Comment: @Ry- the HTML generated is just what I wanted: ```<button class="delete-btn" onclick="deleteEntry(e5f7ce9a-1383-5d7c-9a9b-e8ce73d09041)">D</button>``` I'm using chance.js to generate the id btw.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I was happy to know about the insertAdjacentHTML method, but your example does not work. I think i's because it has a solo backtick at the end... let me know if you review it

Comment: @IsaacMuniz - See my answer. The pastebin copy was missing a line (editing error) with an argument and the leading backtick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `id` values need to be in quotes. You've said:

> the HTML generated is just what I wanted: `<button class="delete-btn" onclick="deleteEntry(e5f7ce9a-1383-5d7c-9a9b-e8ce73d09041)">D</button>`

but look at that code in the attribute:

```
deleteEntry(e5f7ce9a-1383-5d7c-9a9b-e8ce73d09041)
```

That's a syntax error. The string needs to be in quotes.

The minimal change is to add `'`s around `${id}`, assuming you know that `'` will never appear in an `id` value:

```
entries.forEach((entry) => {
  let id = entry.id;
  entryList.innerHTML += `
    <div class="entry">
      <button class="delete-btn" onclick="deleteEntry('${id})'">D</button>
    </div>`;
```

...but as I said in a comment, using `+=` with `innerHTML` and using `onxyz`-attribute-style event handlers are both generally bad ideas:

- When you do `element.innerHTML += "some string"`, the browser has to go through the entire DOM structure in `element` and build up an HTML string to pass to your JavaScript code. Then your JavaScript code has to append to the string and give it back to the browser. Then the browser has to completely remove all contents of `element`, parse the string the JavaScript code gave it, and build new elements for the ones that used to be there (and then also for the new ones). That's a lot of unnecessary work, and it's lossy: Event handlers are lost, the user's focussed element (if it's in `element`) is lost, and current selections in form elements are lost. Instead, consider `createElement`, `appendChild`, `insertBefore`, `insertAdjacentHTML`, insertAdjacenText`, and various other DOM methods.
- `onxyz`-attribute-style event handlers require that you emit syntactically-valid code **and** encode it such that it can appear correctly in an attribute, and also can only use global functions. In general, global functions are best avoided. Instead consider using modern event handling, `addEventListener` and the like. That also would have prevented the problem that lead to the question (not outputting syntactically-valid code).

For example:

```
entries.forEach(({id}) => {
    entryList.insertAdjacentHTML(
        "beforeend",
        `<div class="entry">
            <button class="delete-btn">D</button>
        </div>`
    );
    entryList.lastElementChild.querySelector("button").addEventListener(
        "click", () => deleteEntry(id)
    );
    // ...
```

Here's what I did there:

1. I used destructuring in the parameter list to pick out just the `id` property of the object, so that the code didn't close over the object reference.
2. I used `insertAdjacentHTML` to add the DOM structure to the end of `entryList` *without* destroying and recreating all the previous elements.
3. I used `querySelector` on the new element (`entryList.lastElementChild`) to get the button and used `addEventListener` to add an event handler to it. This avoids any concerns about wrapping `id` values in quotes, and allows you to make `deleteEntry` non-global if you want.

Answer (score -1):

**Here is the working example:**

```js
const entries = [{id: 1, text:'Hello World!'}, {id: 2, text:'ABC'}, {id: 3, text:'XYZ'}];

const entryList = document.querySelector('#entryList');

deleteEntry = function(id) {
  console.log('clicked id : ', id);
}

entries.forEach((entry) => {
  let id = entry.id;
  entryList.innerHTML += `
    <div class="entry">
      <button class="delete-btn" onclick="deleteEntry(${id})">D${id}</button>
    </div>`;
});
```

```html
<div id="entryList"></div>
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Maybe because my id is generated by chance.js ? This is the HTML generated by my code = ```<button class="delete-btn" onclick="deleteEntry(e5f7ce9a-1383-5d7c-9a9b-e8ce73d09041)">D</button>```

Answer (score -2):

for string literals you must use `` quotes

```
onclick=`deleteEntry(${id})`
```

Comment: The OP **is** using a template literal (around the entire three lines of HTML).

Comment: as i can see it's js, not html;)

Comment: I suggest reading the code in the question again, carefully. The `onclick="deleteEntry(${id})"` is only **part** of the overall template literal. The quotes on it are correct.

Comment: What you wrote here is not valid JS, HTML, JSX or whatever related language I know.